# It wakes up the Mac to Leave an Android device connected via USB and Android Studio running

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, android

It does not on Windows, but on OS X, it wakes up the computer from sleep. If Android Studio is not running it does not wake up.

### Steps to reproduce

1. Connect an Android device (I used a Nexus 7 2013).
2. Run Android Studio
3. Click the Apple icon in the status bar, and then click "Sleep".

The computer wakes up automatically a few seconds later. The only walkaround is disconnecting the device or quitting Android Studio. Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: I've never used Android Studio but I suppose it sets up a network connection to your mac. Have you tried turning off _Wake for network access_ in the _Energy Saver_ settings from _System preferences_?

Comment: I had disabled both waking from network and Bluetooth input devices. I guess the USB connection is the culprit. On Windows, there is something like "Allow this device to wake the computer", but OS X does not seem to have such feature.